# Given the following about a function, what can we say about its limit?

Tags: limits, absolute-value, epsilon-delta

If we know the following about the function f:
$|x-1|<0.5 => |f(x)-3|<2$

What can we say about the limit, L, if the limit of f(x) as x approaches 1 exists?

Is the only thing that we can conclude is that L = 3? Or can L be between 1 and 5, if it is the latter could you explain why that is the case?

Additionally, does the fact that the statment is $|x-1|<0.5|$ and not $0<|x-1|<0.5$ have any significance?

Comment: Choose any constant function with value between 1 and 5.

Comment: All you can say is that the limit (if it exists) is that $-1 \le L \le 5$, because $f(x) \in (-1, 5)$ for all $x$ around $1$.

Comment: @user296602 Replace -1 by 1.

Comment: But doesn't the |x−1|<0.5 part of the statement mean that x is approaching 1? And the other half means that f(x) is approaching 3 so L = 5?

Answer (score 1):

We can say that the lmit $1< \mathrm L <5$, but we can not conclude to a specific value of that limit Since we don't know the behaviour of function in $0.5 < x < 1.5$. We can always find a function given a number $c \in (1,5) $ such that $$\lim_{x \to 1} f(x) = c$$

For example, the function $f(x) = c$ does that work.

Comment: What about how x can equal 1 since '0<' is not mentioned, does that change anything?

Comment: @James $\vert x-1\vert$ Already meant that it is $0 \ge |x-1| <1 $ since modulus is always positive.

Comment: Yes but that means that x can equal 1, wouldnt that imply some relation to continuity?